# How to find for the list of code from another table using like function (Oracle sql )?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have table call 'student_table' table which has more than 100 STD_ID's,
which I need to map Student_reg_ID from 'Reg_table' table

student_table format

```
STD_ID
123
456
789
688
```

Reg_table format
column 1 : Student_reg_ID 
column 2 : Reference

```
Student_reg_ID    Reference
23124             stden id 123
56142             customer refer 456
14328             refer -  789
67890             code ref : 688
```

Output needed

```
STD_ID    Student_reg_ID 
123       23124
456       56142
789       14328
688       14328
```

How can i get map the output as shown above ?

I **don't** want to given the more than 100 STD_ID's in like function like below

```
STD_ID Like  '%123% or '%456% or .......
```

How can i get it in a single sql ?

Comment: It looks like you want `reference like '% ' || std_id'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track to use `LIKE` here.  Try this option:

```
SELECT
    st.STD_ID,
    rt.Student_reg_ID
FROM student_table st
LEFT JOIN Reg_table rt
    ON rt.Reference LIKE '%' || st.STD_ID || '%';
```

Note if the `STD_ID` column be a number, then you would first have to cast to text before doing the `LIKE` comparison, i.e. use this:

```
LEFT JOIN Reg_table rt
    ON rt.Reference LIKE '%' || TO_CHAR(st.STD_ID) || '%';
```

**Edit:**

To account for that the `STD_ID` values might not always be three digits, we can use `REGEXP_LIKE` to enforce an exact match when joining:

```
SELECT
    st.STD_ID,
    rt.Student_reg_ID
FROM student_table st
LEFT JOIN Reg_table rt
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(rt.Reference, '(^|\s)' || st.STD_ID || '(\s|$)');
```

Comment: You may as well copy my demo into your answer given they're the same... then I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Nick Nah...don't delete, let it brew, eventually it will get votes.

Comment: This only works, if all STD_ID are three digits long. Otherwise you'd get false positives, e.g. IDs 1, 2, 3, 12, 23, and 123 all matching 'stden id 123'. According to the sample data, lousia rather wants `rt.reference like '% ' || st.std_id'`.

Comment: I see no reason to suspect this edge case.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a numeric ID not having a fixed number of digits an edge case :-) Anyway, I just wanted to point out that the LIKE expression does take the three digits for granted, which you didn't mention in your answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree with your point and I have provided an alternative answer should the IDs not always be three digits.